# Функция date иногда возвращает не правильную дату

Tags: php

Записываю некоторый события на сервере в лог и заметил, что первого числа каждого месяца число записывается неправильно. Еще в двадцатых числах 1 декабря записал.
Вот код:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$time = date('H:i:s');
file_put_contents("log.txt", $date."\t".$time, FILE_APPEND);
```

Результат:

```
2016-11-24  11:35:07    
2016-12-01  01:22:42    
2016-12-01  04:48:42   
2016-11-25  22:03:59
...   
2016-11-30  19:13:23  
2016-11-30  19:20:06   
2016-12-06  08:16:38
2016-12-06  22:14:27
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Могу только сказать, что это очень, очень странно. Посмотрите другие логи на сервере - не сбивалась ли дата там.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Обратите внимание, что в Debian / Ubuntu эта функция вернет системный
>   часовой пояс, определенный в / etc / localtime, если date.timezone не
>   определен, даже с PHP 5.4+ .[Смотреть здесь](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=673763#10)

Можно код продебажить следующим образом:

```
file_put_contents("log.txt", $date."\t".$time.'\t'. date_default_timezone_get(), FILE_APPEND);
```

Или таким вариантом:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
    echo 'Временная зона скрипта отличается от заданной в INI-файле.';
} else {
    echo 'Временные зоны скрипта и настройки INI-файла совпадают.';
}
?>
```

Если вам интересен полный список конфигурационных настроек вашей системы с текущими значениями, то вы можете запустить **phpinfo()** функцию, и получить результирующую страницу. Вы также можете получить доступ к значениям индивидуально сконфигурированных директив в процессе выполнения, используя **ini_get()** или **get_cfg_var()**.

Удачи !